A reminder about plagarism
Spambots are becoming more sophisticated. Recently, we've had a rash of them on Bitcoin SE which programmatically write answers. They copy text from a related article, and post it here.
This creates a bunch of problems. Aside from raising the rep of the spambot, this violates the copyright of the copied site. Also, the answers are terrible, often offtopic, and not checked for any errors.
I'd like to give two reminders:
Please flag plagiarized posts
If you see a slightly odd answer, which doesn't seem entirely on-point, copy two sentences from the body of it, wrap it in quote marks, and Google it.
If hits come up from elsewhere on the web, flag it! Flag as "in need of moderator attention," with the reason "copied from http://example.com"
We don't want to give these 'bots a foothold.
Don't post something copied from another site without giving a source
See also: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/referencing
We're going to delete it on the spot, rather than warning you as we've done in the past. 
The storm has passed; we're back to warning.

Why are the bots doing this?

@WizardOfOzzie Our spam algorithm takes rep into account a lot. More rep and more positively-voted answers = less chance of being filtered.
